# calculate a limitation

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f(x)$ is continuous and positive on $[0,1]$
  Prove that
$$\lim_{p \to 0^+}(\int_{0}^{1}f^p(x)\text dx)^{1/p}=e^{\int_{0}^{1}\ln f(x)\text dx} $$.

This is my former question.Actually I have get a way by consider the limitation:
$$ \lim_{x \to 0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=e $$
So I changed the form :$$(\int_{0}^{1}f^p(x)\text dx)^{1/p}=(1+\int_{0}^{1}f^p(x)\text dx-1)^{\frac{1}{\int_{0}^{1}f^p(x)\text dx-1}\cdot\frac{\int_{0}^{1}f^p(x)\text dx-1}{p}}$$

Then in this situation I think the problem is equal to prove that:
$$\lim_{p\to0^+}\frac{\int_{0}^{1}f^p(x)\text dx-1}{p}=\int_{0}^{1}\ln f(x)\text dx$$

I have considered  mean value theorem and L'Hospital rule. But doesn't work.

So I really want to know is there any way to prove the last equation. Or I had thinking in a wrong way at first.

PS:My first and second question has deleted and this is my third question.And I am in a danger of being blocked to ask question. I really have searched before asking.If the question is also duplicate and too stupid.Please comment and let know.

Comment: L'Hopital rule *does* work. What is the derivative of $f(x)^p$ with respect to $p$?

Comment: Oh yeah, It's right ! In the last days I always consider derivative with respect to x.Thank you !